# How to make the default setting of Lite-On Ethernet off?

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I have a Realtek Internet stick that I did a lot of shenanigans to install, and it works really well. However, every time I reboot the computer, it automatically tries to connect the Lite-On Ethernet. It also seems to randomly try to turn Lite-On Ethernet back on, even when I manually turn it off. Of course, it can't connect because I don't have an ethernet cable plugged into my computer, so it constantly sends "Lite-On Ethernet connection failed" messages, and it's really annoying. Is there a way to make it turn off automatically?

Results of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 045e:00f7 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam VX-1000
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0d8c:0012 C-Media Electronics, Inc. USB Audio Device
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 413c:3012 Dell Computer Corp. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 045e:00b0 Microsoft Corp. Digital Media Pro Keyboard
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac WLAN Adapter 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Results of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Results of `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:b5:94:7b:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1a:a0:d2:a8:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlxe84e06562df0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 2312 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:4e:06:56:2d:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.40.121/24 brd 192.168.40.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlxe84e06562df0
       valid_lft 23363sec preferred_lft 23363sec
    inet6 fe80::e6d0:b064:844f:59b9/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:d1:df:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:d1:df:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `lsb_release -a`

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Isn't the Lite-On ethernet a USB device? I don't see it in your `lsusb` readings. What "shenanigans" did you go through to install it? Did you have to download and install Lite-On's driver and not the preferred open source driver? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I'm trying to stop the "Lite-On Ethernet" from trying to connect BECAUSE I got a different internet driver and the Lite-On Ethernet doesn't have a device connected. I install a certain package to get my Realtek Internet stick working.

Comment: Please add the output of `ip a`

Comment: I am trying to find out about the Lite-On ethernet BECAUSE, in order to stop it from the undesired activity, I suspect that we need to manipulate its driver or substitute a different driver. I am confused as to why you need to install nstall a certain package to get your Realtek Internet stick working as it appears to be working perfectly. It has an IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the **Wired Connection** settings panel, and uncheck **Connect automatically**.

[image]

Comment: Seems like it worked! Thank you!

Comment: @SyntheticHuman Great news! Thanks for the feedback.